# How to unset an environment variable in Eclipse run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, docker-compose

I have an external run configuration for docker-compose, and need to disable TLS verification because my VPN messes with my connection and I connect through a forwarded port because of that.

The only way I have found to do that for docker-compose is to unset the environment variable DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY (setting it to 0 does not work). Note that setting it to an empty String in the environment variables view did not work (see screenshot).

How can I unset the variable?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Replace native environment with specified environment`?

Comment: @TillBrychcy Yes, but that messes things up completely because other needed environment variables are missing and I don't know which are necessary. On the other hand, I could just select all environment variables in the "Select" dialog and then unset this one. Hang on, I'll test...

Comment: @TillBrychcy I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @TillBrychcy I did, in the end, get it to work, I was just missing one more variable that needed to be unset, and some more configuration for my docker daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom of the dialog, **choose *Replace native environment with specified environment*** and define the **variables you want to keep by using the `env_var` to set the value**, e. g. set the value of `DOCKER_HOST` to `${env_var:DOCKER_HOST}`.