# Ecilpse : 'VM arguments' vs 'Variables' (see image)

Tags: eclipse, jvm-arguments, vmargs

What is the difference between adding 'VM arguments' using text box and 'Variables' button in eclipse?

Refer to pointers in image.

[image]

Comment: Only the text box determines the actual arguments. The “Variables...” button only opens a convenience dialog to browse and select variables defined within Eclipse, to be inserted into the arguments, just like the completion in the Java source code editor.

Comment: The _Program arguments_ are the `args` in `public static void main(final String[] args)`. The VM (virtual machine) arguments are e.g. `-Xms256m`, `-Xmx1024m`, `-XX:+UseG1GC`, `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication`, `-DmyProperty=foo`, etc. And the _Variables..._ are Eclipse variables that can be used to define these variables.

Comment: @Holger Variables->Edit Variables ->New   .  allows us to create new variable

Comment: The new variable that you can create is not used for anything unless you include it in the Program or VM arguments text.

Comment: @VikashYadav The _Edit Variables..._ button is a shortcut to the _Run/Debug > String Substituation_ preferences to extend the global variable pool. Variables created in this way can be used e.g. in the [_Environment_ tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742640/6505250) or in other launch configurations as well.

Comment: ok. Variables button was just aside text box so I thought both would have same functionality if varaible is added in any one of them.